# How to retrieve the sort column and direction of a grid using Ext/JS 4.1

Tags: extjs, coldfusion, extjs4.1, coldfusion-2016

We upgraded from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 2016 and some code that we had been using is no longer working. It looks like ColdFusion 2016 is using Ext/JS 4.1 and I'm not sure how to retrieve this information using this version.

Current code is:

```
var mygrid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('rosterGrid');
var params = mygrid.getStore().lastOptions.params;
var sort = params.sort;
var dir = params.dir;
```

I cannot find the equivalent for the `lastOptions.params` in 4.1.  I need to get the sort column and direction for the grid.

Comment: You should look at Sencha 4.1 docs. There is no more lastOptions and params object. To send and use some additional data now you can use extraParams object of Proxy. As I remember, you should use store.getProxy().extraParams

Comment: You should use this. `sortableColumns : Boolean`. Check the http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`var sorter = mygrid.getStore().sorters.getAt(0);
var sort = sorter.property;
var dir = sorter.direction;`

Comment: It returns sorter is undefined.  Looking through the Ext/JS documentation I dont see property or direction under sorter

Comment: Documentation - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter. Here, sorter will be undefined if there is no sort currently applied to the store. In that case do this:
var sort = sorter ? sorter.property : '';

Try this fiddle. It works - http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/3237/

Comment: You were correct it was undefined if no sort was given originally.  The end code looks like this:        
     var sorter = mygrid.getStore().sorters.getAt(0);
     if (typeof sorter != 'undefined') {
   var sort = sorter.property;
   var dir = sorter.direction;
  } else {
      var sort = 'startDate';
      var dir = 'ASC';   
  }

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [inQstvJS` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42220389/104223), here is what my final code looked like.

```
var sorter = mygrid.getStore().sorters.getAt(0); 
if (typeof sorter != 'undefined') { 
   var sort = sorter.property; 
   var dir = sorter.direction; 
} else { 
   var sort = 'startDate'; 
   var dir = 'ASC'; 
}
```